# Execute a file from tkinter (GUI) with exec

Tags: python, tkinter

I am using python 3.4.2, windows 8.1 and I have a GUI "reload 0.py" that sums two values when I press a button, and shows the result in a box. I have another GUI "reload1.py" with a button. I want to open and "reload0.py" when I press the button in "reload1.py".

I am using this in the button

```
exec(open("C:\\Users\\me\\Desktop\\rel\\reload0.py").read())
```

but I am getting the following error

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\idlelib\run.py", line 121, in main
    seq, request = rpc.request_queue.get(block=True, timeout=0.05)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\queue.py", line 175, in get
    raise Empty
queue.Empty
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1533, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "<string>", line 24, in mOp
NameError: name 'value1' is not defined
```

If I run "reload0.py" alone, it works, if I put the command in python shell, it works, but when I put the same command in the "reload1.py" button it does not work.

Comment: Why are you using exec rather than importing the other file as a module? While you can make it work with exec, you are probably making the problem harder than it needs to be. What are you really trying to accomplish?

Comment: Does both reload1.py and reload0.py each create a root window?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've never seen anyone code callback functions and guis using exec so i cannot tell you why it is not working.

You should put the code in result0.py into a class or function,
That way you can simply import the function/class and use it in a callback

Let us assume the code below is result0.py

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk

class SomeWindow(tk.Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Toplevel.__init__(self, parent)
        lab1 = ttk.Label(self, text='hihihi')
        lab1.pack()
        lab2 = tkt.Label(self, text='fdsfsfds')
        lab2.pack()
```

Now in result1.py we import the SomeWindow and bind it to the callback

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk

from result0 import SomeWindow

root = tk.Tk()

but = ttk.Button(root, text='press me', command=lambda: SomeWindow(root))
but.pack()

tk.mainloop()
```

If you are just getting started with gui programming, you might want to take a look at the model view controller (MVC) design pattern

http://tkinter.unpythonic.net/wiki/ToyMVC

Some good tkinter references are:

http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/

http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/index.html

https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.html#module-tkinter

Also tkinter 8.6 was released in March 2015 but most documentation and tutorials for 8.5 still apply.